# How to rebuild a Widget when data/value change?

Tags: listview, dynamic, dart, flutter

I want to make a List that when data change from a value (Not form JSON)then display the values :

```
ProcedureList(brand: widget.brandSelected, filteredkits: snapshot.data,),
```

This is the list widget that I pass 2 values Brand Selected form other widget and a List .

How I can do a Dynamic List that shows when I change the value . there is the main widget that I guess in that need StatefulWidget for when brandSelected change (Change when function is called on other widget) then rebuild ListView with the new brandSelected :

```
class LoanerBookingCatalog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoanerBookingCatalog createState() => _LoanerBookingCatalog();

  String brandSelected ;
  List<Kits> filteredkids;
  bool changed = false;

  getBrandSelected(String brand, List<Kits> filteredkitsbones){
    print(brand);
    brandSelected  = brand;
    filteredkids = filteredkitsbones;
    changed = true;
  }



}


class _LoanerBookingCatalog extends State<LoanerBookingCatalog>{

final KitsData kitsFetcher = KitsData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0), // here the desired height
        child: new AppBar(
          leading: SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
            width: 20.0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Image.asset(
                "images/backbtn.png",
                height: 5.0,
                width: 5.0,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
          title: new Text(
            "PRODUCTS CATALOGUE",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              color: Colors.grey[700],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: kitsFetcher.fetch(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Kits>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var bonesWidget = BonesWidget(
                kitlist: snapshot.data,
                getBrandSelectedandList: widget.getBrandSelected,
              );
              return Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage("images/backgroundCatalog.png"))),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        bonesWidget,
                        widget.changed == true ? Container():
                        ProcedureList(brand: widget.brandSelected, filteredkits: snapshot.data,),
```

And the ProcedureList WidgetCode :

```
class ProcedureList extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _ProcedureList createState() => _ProcedureList();

  String brand ;
  List<Kits> filteredkits;
  ProcedureList({Key key, this.brand, this.filteredkits}) : super(key: key);
}

class _ProcedureList extends State<ProcedureList> {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          var procedureList = widget.filteredkits.where((kit) => kit.brand == widget.brand)
            .map((kit) => kit.procedure)
            .toList();

    return Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0),
        child: new ListView.builder(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount:  procedureList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    width: 300.0,
                    height: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                    child: new Text(widget.brand),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60.0,
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: procedureList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: new Card(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: new Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text(procedureList[index])
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Data changes when the function is called on the widget called Bones widget then I get 2 parameters : 1º String Brand , 2º List . With this two parameters I need that ProcedureListWidget refresh every time I use the function because then I get the data.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What kinda of change?

Comment: At first the value is null when I click on other list get the value of selected and then I need to "build" the other ListView

Comment: selected value is present in parent ?

Comment: some code would help

Comment: Added more code

Comment: I am very sorry for asking so many questions. Can you please point where the data is changing and which widget need to refresh.

Comment: Data changes when the function is called on the widget called Bones widget then I get 2 parameters : 1º String Brand , 2º List . With this two parameters I need that ProcedureListWidget refresh every time I use the function because then I get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is when you want to change the value you should call the `setState`  function in a state and the widget will be rendered again. Example:

```
setState(() {
      loading = true;
});
```

And obviously, this function is accessible in a `StatefulWidget`